# Multi scope selection for textMateRules

Tags: visual-studio-code

Trying to make the move from webstorm to vscode.

Im trying to figure out how to target textMateRules more accurately.
Specifically demanding more than one scope match.

I read somewhere that you did it like this, but it gets overwritten by the default `entity.name.function`.

```
"scope": [
          "entity.name.function meta.method.declaration"
        ],
```

Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 6):

I had not realized **ordering** was important.

```
"scope": [
          "meta.method.declaration entity.name.function"
        ],
```

Did the trick.

Comment: Have you figured out the logic for the correct order? Do I simply need to test either way and see which order works?

Answer (score 0):

In my VS Code (1.63.2) for multiple scopes I use this code:

```
"scope": [
    "entity.name.function",
    "meta.method.declaration"
],
```

Comment: If you list multiple scopes like this, those are logically `OR`'d together. When you use multiple scope names in a single string, those are logically `AND`'d together. However, the order of the scope names in a single string seem to be meaningful but I haven't yet found documentation about this. This is different from CSS specificity rules where the order of e.g. different class names do not change the specificity of the selector.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to use the textmate scopes from the inspector in the opposite order (from bottom to top).

For example, I tried to apply my rule to `array` keyword followed by a round bracket (PHP).
The scope inspector showed the scopes in this order:

```
    support.function.construct.php
    meta.array.php
    meta.function-call.php
    source.php
    meta.embedded.block.php
    text.html.php
```

Like this:

[image: Scope inspector with selected array keyword followed by a round bracket]

I took the first two and reversed the order in my `settings.json` file like this.
In the screenshot above you can see that the rule is already applied.

```
{
    "scope": "meta.array.php support.function.construct.php"
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#000ba3",
        "fontStyle": "bold"
    }
}
```